# Applescript Excel: Using String From List To Use Worksheet

Tags: excel, list, applescript

I'm trying to make a simple script for email automation, it's going to get emails from different Excel sheets in the same workbook. I've made a list of the sheet names I want to use, and want to create a prompt with 'choose from list' to create a variable, and use it when creating emails. However, whenever I use the script, Excel only gets data from the active sheet, and disregards my assigned variable for the sheet name. Here's my code snippet:

```
set LanguageList to {"Albanian", "Bosnian", "Bulgarian", "Croatian", "Czech", "Danish", "Dutch", "Finnish", "Hungarian", "Norwegian", "Polish", "Portugese", "Romanian", "Serbian", "Slovak", "Slovenian", "Spanish", "Swedish"}

set LanguageSheet to choose from list LanguageList with prompt "Select a language:"
activate object sheet LanguageSheet
if LanguageSheet = false then
    error number -128
    --quit workbook EmailList
end if
```

I added the `activate object sheet LanguageSheet` to test what's going on, and here's the error Script Editor throws at me in the terminal:

```
error "Microsoft Excel got an error: The object you are trying to access does not exist" number -1728 from sheet {"Bosnian"}
```

I guess I can create a long list of if's and use it to refer to the sheet index, while that **may** work as a solution, I don't understand why this doesn't work. Is there a flaw in my logic?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `choose from list` command returns a list, for example:

```
--> {"Bosnian"}
```

The `activate object worksheet` will not work with a list so you would need to change it to `get item 1 of list, like so:

```
set LanguageList to {"Albanian", "Bosnian", "Croatian", "Danish"}
set LanguageSheet to choose from list LanguageList with prompt "Select a language:"
        
activate object worksheet (get item 1 of LanguageSheet)

--> "Bosnian"
```

Alternatively, you can relocate the 'get item 1' to the 'set LanguageSheet' command, which simplifies the 'activate object worksheet' command.

```
    set LanguageList to {"Albanian", "Bosnian", "Croatian", "Danish"}
    set LanguageSheet to item 1 of (get choose from list LanguageList with prompt "Select a language:")
    activate object worksheet LanguageSheet
```

Comment: Not sure if here's the right place to thank you, but thank you. Not only I could solve my problem with a few quick modifications, I learned that 'choose from list' returns a list itself!

Comment: Glad to help. I find that it can be useful —especially with an unfamiliar command— to just see what the output/result of the command is before trying to work with it. Once  I started doing that, I saw fewer errors and was able to resolve those errors more quickly. Ironically, it also helped me grasp the documentation better.

Comment: I should add that the reason (probably) that it returns a list is that it is possible to select multiple items (if you include that option).